# Eclipse does not show javadoc comments on anonymous inner class

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, javadoc

I have following class with a method to be overriden by its object. It has a comment that I want it to show.

```
public class Screen()
{

   /**
    * Called when display resumes
    */
   public void onResume()
   {

   }
}
```

Then I instantiate an object from this class as anonymous inner class as such:

```
public Screen myScreen = new Screen()
{

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {

    }
}
```

**I want to be able to see comment of the method when I hover over onResume, in the object myScreen.
But Eclipse does not show the comment.**

Although, It shows the comment when I inherit from that class like this.

```
public class SomeScreen extends Screen
{
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {

    }   
}
```

Comment: This is not a javadoc comment. Javadoc comments start with `/**` instead of `/*`

Comment: Sorry, i wrote it here wrong. It was suppose to be /**

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with Eclipse Kepler. Maybe this is a bug in eclipse.

Comment: Does it show the comment, when you do like the code snippet in the middle? and hover over onResume?

Comment: yes, like expected, i can read the comment.